# Switching tab in the Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, dom-events

I want to know a tab event for Firefox extension to capture the event of switching from new tab to the older tab. I want to know event for switching from the new tab to the old tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event listener:

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("select", function(event)
{
  // Tab switched, do something
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the [TabSelect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_tab_selection) event.

Comment: Interesting. I'm pretty sure I was detecting the same thing using the usual `select` event on the `tabbrowser` element. I wonder what this `TabSelect` event is good for.

Comment: Dunno.  There being more than one way to do things in mozilla does not surprise me.  :)

Comment: `TabSelect` is a non-standard event so somebody must have implemented it for a reason. Looking at the source code, the main difference seems to be that `TabSelect` isn't being fired for tab preview (a UI feature that has never been enabled by default). And there is the nice fact that you can use `TabSelect` in Firefox Mobile whereas `select` won't be fired there.

Comment: i wanna know event to capture the switch between tabs in firefox

Comment: Wait, you want to know which even to use to capture tabs being switched in Firefox?